# Qt Quick 2 + GLSL shockwave effect multitouch

Tags: qt, glsl, qtquick2

I am using QtQuick 2 and trying to simulate a water surface, where waves can be launched when touched ; to begin, I took some code from Qt example and try to reuse GLSL shader from qmlvideofx example. The shader works correctly, but defines only one center for a wave.
So if a new touchpoint is send, first wave is stopped...

Is there a way in GLSL to have an array of points, and loop through it ? I must say I'm pretty new with this language.. ;)

Here is my fragment shader :

```
uniform float centerX;
uniform float centerY;
uniform float dividerValue;
uniform float granularity;
uniform float centerX;
uniform float centerY;
uniform float dividerValue;
uniform float granularity;
uniform float time;
uniform float weight;

uniform sampler2D source;
uniform lowp float qt_Opacity;
varying vec2 qt_TexCoord0;

void main() {
   vec2 uv = qt_TexCoord0.xy;
   vec2 tc = qt_TexCoord0;
   vec2 center = vec2(centerX, centerY);
   const vec3 shock = vec3(10.0, 1.5, 0.1);
   if (uv.x < dividerValue) {
      float distance = distance(uv, center);
      if ((distance <= (time + shock.z)) &&
          (distance >= (time - shock.z))) {
         float diff = (distance - time);
         float powDiff = 1.0 - pow(abs(diff*shock.x), shock.y*weight);
         float diffTime = diff  * powDiff;
         vec2 diffUV = normalize(uv - center);
         tc += (diffUV * diffTime);
      }
   }
   gl_FragColor = qt_Opacity * texture2D(source, tc);
}
```